# JVM crash on Cloud Foundary

Tags: java, cloud, native, cloud-foundry

My App is crashing in Cloud foundary and while getting crashed it is showing below memory statics:

```
Memory usage:
       Heap memory: init 603979776, used 37501288, committed 583860224, max 583860224
          Hint: Heap memory is over 95% full. To increase it, increase the container size.
       Non-heap memory: init 7667712, used 114661704, committed 124698624, max 421101568
    Memory pool usage:
       CodeHeap 'non-nmethods': init 2555904, used 1390464, committed 2555904, max 5828608
       CodeHeap 'profiled nmethods': init 2555904, used 20410240, committed 26214400, max 131301376
       CodeHeap 'non-profiled nmethods': init 2555904, used 5704448, committed 7012352, max 131305472
       Metaspace: init 0, used 79194184, committed 80527360, max 80527360
          Hint: Metaspace is over 95% full. To increase it, set -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize to a suitable value.
       Compressed Class Space: init 0, used 7962368, committed 8388608, max 72138752
       Eden Space: init 161087488, used 147696, committed 161087488, max 161087488
       Survivor Space: init 20119552, used 0, committed 20119552, max 20119552
   2019-03-15T17:52:16.76+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR jvmkill killing current process
       Tenured Gen: init 402653184, used 37353592, committed 402653184, max 402653184
    ERR Thread dump triggered at 2019-03-15 12:22:16
```

If we see carefully my heap size is around **603.97Mb** and used is just **37.5Mb**. Still logs are saying heap is **95%** full. I can see from logs that Metaspace is over **95%** full that seems to be correct.

Not sure why JVM is saying heap is **95%** fill. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can adjust the Metaspace size so that there is sufficient space and retest. Right now there's two issues being reported heap and metaspace are over 95% full. Get rid of the obvious one (metaspace) and see what happens then. Does it still report heap is full? Do both issues go away? Also, you might want to use a second source of information like Java NMT to capture memory usage. You could then contrast what's being reported here versus NMT as a sanity check.

Comment: how do you print the hints?